# How are variables related when using an allocator in C++?

Tags: c++, allocator

I'm studying this piece of code and what I don't understand is how `p`, `q` and `r` are related. We assign `p` to `q` and `p` to `r`, then display `r`, even though we do the increment on `q`.

Then this `do ... while` loop:

```
do {
    cout<< "here" << *r << endl;
} while (++r != q);
```

How does it work? What are `r` and `q` equal to?

This is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    allocator<string> alloc;
    auto const p = alloc.allocate(5);
    auto q=p;
    alloc.construct(q++);
    alloc.construct(q++, 10, 'c');
    alloc.construct(q++, "hi");
    auto r=p;
    
    do{
        cout<< *r << endl;
    }while (++r != q);
    
    std::cout<<"done"<<endl;
    
    while (q != p){
        alloc.destroy(--q);
    }
    
    q=p; r=p;
    alloc.construct(q++, 10, 'a');
    alloc.construct(q++, "hi again");
    
    do{
        cout<< "here" << *r << endl;
    }while (++r != q);
    
    alloc.deallocate(p, 5);
}
```

The output is:

```
output:
cccccccccc
hi
done
hereaaaaaaaaaa
herehi again
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Aside: It is *really* confusing to have `do ... while()` and `while ...` loops with no `{}`. *Every* control flow should start a new block.

Comment: @Caleth hopefully this is more clear now?

Comment: @moey Not really, since you now deleted all the formatting that Caleth carefully put in. Code indentation is *important* for readability.

Comment: I'd recommend using a text editor that understands C++ enough to autoformat your code as you go.

Comment: will do for future @Caleth

Comment: This is all using rather basic pointer arithmetic, what part exactly confuses you?

Comment: @UnholySheep the `auto` hiding that there are pointers might be confusing

Comment: thats correct @Caleth, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is a `std::string * const`, aka "constant pointer to mutable string". `q` and `r` are initialised to *copies* of `p`, meaning they are `std::string *`, aka "mutable pointer to mutable string".

`p` always points to the first element of the allocated array. `q` and `r` are modified to point to other elements of the array.

The first block

```
auto q=p;
alloc.construct(q++);
alloc.construct(q++, 10, 'c');
alloc.construct(q++, "hi");
```

constructs 3 `std::string` objects, at consecutive positions in the array, starting with the first, incrementing `q` each time. `q` ends up pointing one-past the last `std::string`, to the forth element of the array.

The next block

```
auto r=p;    
do{
    cout<< *r << endl;
}while (++r != q);
```

displays these strings. After this, both `q` and `r` point to the forth element of the array.

The next block

```
while (q != p){
    alloc.destroy(--q);
}
```

destroys each of those strings, in reverse order of construction. `q` ends up pointing to the first element, the same as `p`.

The first statement of the next block is a tautology, it sets `q` to the value it currently has, and then constructs 2 more strings. `r` is also reset to `p`.

```
q=p; r=p;
alloc.construct(q++, 10, 'a');
alloc.construct(q++, "hi again");
```

The next block displays those new strings, prepending "here".

```
do{
    cout<< "here" << *r << endl;
}while (++r != q);
```

Finally the array is deallocated, without destroying the `std::string` objects. This might leak memory that the strings allocate, as their destructors are not run.

```
alloc.deallocate(p, 5);
```

Comment: thank you @Caleth